# How to implement a realtime, twitter like universal message console

Tags: logging, real-time, aggregate

I have an e-commercial site that have a lot of sub systems, every system has some event, when the event occurs or finishes, a log will generated, I want to aggregate all this info together and shows on one page in realtime，like twitter. Any good idea/mature solution to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[AMQP](http://www.amqp.org/confluence/display/AMQP/Advanced+Message+Queuing+Protocol) and [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/faq.html) are very popular for scenarios like this.